Inner header and Outer header in tunnel packet
What should be at Inner header and Outer header in tunnel packet ?

And then we have tunnel IP address(for both router), tunnel source IP address, tunnel destination IP address.

In my understanding, for packet send from R2 to R1

Outer IP header

Source : Tunnel Source (202.123.170.1)
Destination : Tunnel Destination (210.115.30.10)


Inner IP header

Source : Actual source from network behind R2
Destination : Acutal destination that is from network behind R1



But I am not sure about that, and what would be the use case for Tunnel IP address (192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2) ??

The Outer IP header should be Public IP from ISP in real world situation right ?

That is basically correct. As a rule of thumb, the outer packet uses public IP addresses, the inner private ones.

what would be the use case for Tunnel IP address (192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2) ?

The tunnel IP addresses serve as numbered endpoints for the (inner) tunnel. Depending on the protocols and devices used, those addresses are not always necessary. Since a tunnel is a point-to-point connection, addressing is basically redundant.
Note that basic GRE does not provide encryption, so your tunnel over the open Internet might be listened in.
